# Extract Specific RANGE of columns in numpy array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array :

```
e = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 5, 3, 2, 5],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 3, 5]])
```

I want to extract array by its columns in RANGE, if I want to take column in range 1 until 5, It will return

```
e = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3, 5, ],
              [ 5,  6,  7, 5, ],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 4, ]])
```

How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can just use e[:, 1:5] to retrive what you want.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: e = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
   ...:               [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 5, 3, 2, 5],
   ...:               [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 3, 5]])

In [3]: e[:, 1:5]
Out[3]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  4]])
```

> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: I think you mean `e[:, 1:5]`.

Comment: If the array consists of decimal nos. and I wish to retrieve e[:, 1.1:5.2] i.e extract data-set inbetween 1.1 to 5.2 and its values in corresponding columns, how do we do that?

Comment: What if I want to select to ranges; let's say columns 1:3 and 5:7?

Answer (score 5):

Numpy row and column indices start counting at 0.

The rows are specified first and then the column with a comma to separate the row from column.

The ":" (colon) is used to shortcut all rows or all columns when it is used alone.

When the row or column specifier has a range, then the ":" is paired with numbers that specify the inclusive start range and the exclusive end range.

For example

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array( [ [ 1, 2, 3, ],
                       [ 4, 5, 6, ],
                       [ 7, 8, 9  ] ]  )

first_row = np_array[0,:]
first_row
output: array([1, 2, 3])

last_column = np_array[:,2]
last_column
output: array([3, 6, 9])

first_two_vals = np_array[0,0:2]
first_two_vals
output: array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.take with specifying axis=1

```
import numpy as np
e = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 5, 3, 2, 5],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 3, 5]])
e = np.take(e, [1,2,3,4], axis=1)

output:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  4]])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html